# an alert function that i created is calling several times for no reason

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am working on a project using firebase database and I save the users with their displayName instead of uid. I check if the displayName of the user who is trying to signup is on the list of displayNames on firebase and if not I allow user to signup with that displayName.

here is my signUp function;

```
func signUp(email: String, password: String) {
    //gets the user data in the firebase
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.value) { [self] (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(self.userNameTxtField.text!){ //checking the displayName
            self.present(alertFunction(message: "Seçmiş olduğunuz kullanıcı adı daha önceden alınmış."), animated: true)
        } else {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {...} else {
                    self.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my signIn function;

```
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {...} else {
        
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        //create database reference
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        //create new child and write a value on the existance child
        if self.userNameTxtField.text == ""{
            print("User Name can not be nill!")
            self.present(self.alertFunction(message: "Kullanıcı adı boş bırakılamaz"), animated: true)
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "userSignedIn")
            if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest() {
                currentUser.displayName = self.userNameTxtField.text!
                currentUser.commitChanges(completion: { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        print("DisplayName changed")
                        self.ref.child("users").child(currentUser.displayName!).setValue(["nickname": self.userNameTxtField.text ?? ""])
                        self.ref.child("users/\(currentUser.displayName!)/step_count").setValue(Int(0))
                        self.ref.child("users/\(currentUser.displayName!)/total_point").setValue(Int(0))
                        self.ref.child("users/\(currentUser.displayName!)/onesignal_player_id").setValue("")

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMainFromRegister", sender: self)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally here is my actionFunction;

```
func alertFunction(message: String) -> UIAlertController {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Uyarı!", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    return alert
}
```

I call the signUp function after a button clicked and signUp func is calling the signIn function and if everything goes fine signIn function calls the performSegue function but after the performSegue

> snapshot.hasChild(self.userNameTxtField.text!)

is triggered several time and the alert;

> self.present(alertFunction(message: "Seçmiş olduğunuz kullanıcı adı daha önceden alınmış."), animated: true)

is displaying for no reason.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
// listens for any change
.observe(.value) { [self] (snapshot) in
```

with

```
// listens for a change only once 
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

When I used "weak" there were several red errors but when I deleted it, it worked. Why we should use weak?

Comment: long story read https://www.advancedswift.com/strong-weak-unowned-in-swift/